# When two images are overlapped, one is disappeared. How to solve it?

Tags: android, andengine

There are two images.

```
//1. 
player = new Sprite(300, 670, this.mChaTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

//2.
body[i] = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ball[i], BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
ball[i].setUserData(body[i]);
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ball[i], body[i], true, true));
this.mScene.registerTouchArea(ball[i]);
this.mScene.attachChild(ball[i]);
```

ball is defined TouchArea, but player is not.
player is disappeared, when two images(player and ball) are overlapped and I touch the player.
The player should not disappeared.
How can I solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this could help: use

```
final ILayer layer = mEngine.getScene().getLayer(YOUR_LAYER);
layer.addEntity(ball);
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(ball.getPhysicsConnector());
```

Don't register each ball, but use onSceneTouchEvent
then test for touch on ball:

```
for (Ball ball : balls) {

if (ball.contains(eventx, eventy)) {
//touching the ball
}
```